# Unable to move browser window to edge of screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, userscripts

I've got a very simple userscript running through Tampermonkey to automatically resize and position popout chat for Twitch when the window is opened;

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.resizeTo(356, 1087);
    window.moveTo(2560, 360);
})();
```

I use Firefox, and ideally I would want it to move the window over to my right hand monitor. However it seems like this is impossible, as Firefox clamps `moveTo` to the same screen. The best I can do seems to require at least one drag to the destination window.

Aside from that, the script seems to function and moves it towards the left edge. However, it doesn't seem to be able to actually move it to the (0,0) left hand edge of the screen.

No matter the values I use, or even if I test with `moveBy` and deliberately try to force the window over, it leaves a gap down the edge of the monitor of 8 pixels. I've attached an image below showing this, no matter the commands I use I cannot get it to move further left towards the edge of the right hand screen.

I'm using Firefox 120.0.1, and Windows 11.

[image: image showing the gap left by the window]

Comment: How do you run that script? Do you open the developer tool?

Comment: I run it as a userscript with Tampermonkey.